# Tango with Django 1.9 on Django 2.0 - "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Tags: python, django, django-2.0

I am, probably stupidly, attempting to go through Tango with Django 1.9 on newly released Django 2.0. I am up to [chapter 6](https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django_19/blob/master/manuscript/chapter6-models-templates-views.md) and am getting the following error.

[image]

The error pertains to my views.py file (below) with the lines,

```
context_dict['pages'] = pages
context_dict['category'] = category
```

seemingly the culprits. Has the way in which variables are assigned to dictionaries changed in Django 2.0 or is this a Python issue? Can provide code from all other application files.

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rango.models import Category, Page

def index(request):

    category_list = Category.objects.order_by('-likes')[:5]
    context_dict = {'categories':category_list}
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context=context_dict)

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'rango/about.html')

def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    context_dict = []

    try:

        category = Category.objects.get(slug=category_name_slug)

        pages = Page.objects.filter(category=category)

        context_dict['pages'] = pages
        context_dict['category'] = category

    except Category.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['category'] = None
        context_dict['pages'] = None

    return render(request, 'rango/category.html', context_dict)
```

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category,self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self): # For Python 2, use __unicode__ too
    return self.title

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title','category','url')
```

**Pages (from admin page)**
[image: Pages (from admin page)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    context_dict = []
```

where `context_dict` should be a dictionary, not a list:

```
def show_category(request, category_name_slug):
    context_dict = {}
    #also valid: context_dict = dict()
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much!!